# C# How to terminate application.run()

Tags: c#

I would like to know, how to terminate a program using, for example, the escape key. 
In general, what I have to do to stop it after the application.run(..)?

How can I insert this

```
 private void myForm_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) { 
           if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) { 
               Application.Exit(); 
            } 
        }
```

in the code below

```
static void Main()
    {

        using (WinForm new_form = new WinForm())
        {
            new_form.InitializeComponent();
            new_form.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
            new_form.InitializeDevice();
            new_form.LoadSurfaces();
            new_form.Set3D();
            Application.Run(new_form);
         }
```

}

Comment: As it stands this is too broad to answer - can you edit your question into something more specifc?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not "clear". What I want to say is that after application.run() is called i would like to end it using the method suggested my by Cody Gray(using the escape key). So I tried to ask how can I insert/call/use it in the part of code I posted. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

**Call the [`Application.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) method.**

> The `Exit` method stops all running message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the application. This method does not necessarily force the application to exit. The `Exit` method is typically called from within a message loop, and **forces `Run` to return**. To exit a message loop for the current thread only, call `ExitThread`.
>
> `Exit` raises the following events and performs the associated conditional actions:
>
> - A `FormClosing` event is raised for every form represented by the `OpenForms` property. This event can be canceled by setting the Cancel property of their `FormClosingEventArgs` parameter to true.
> - If one of more of the handlers cancels the event, then `Exit` returns without further action. Otherwise, a `FormClosed` event is raised for every open form, then all running message loops and forms are closed.

To do this when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed, you might want to handle the [`KeyUp` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) for your form:

```
private void myForm_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `WinForms` then go for [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx).

If you're using `WPF` then use [Application.Current.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx)();

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Application.Exit()` or close all active forms. E.g. you could simply add `Close();` to the `KeyDown` event handler in your form.